# How do I get hibernate to execute CREATE DATABASE if necessary for postgresql when hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hbm2ddl

I am using [spring-roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo), [gwt](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) to make a website. We are using the in memory database HyperSonic, but I am trying to switch to [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Everything works fine if I used the [jdbc3 driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc3). The only problem is I have to separately execute the `CREATE DATABASE` statement outside of hibernate before it will create the tables via `[hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)` being set to create. Is their another option I can set to cause hibernate to do the `CREATE DATABASE` if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You have to do a `CREATE DATABASE` using a template database (normally `template1`). The normal sequence of events is:

1. Connect to `template1` database
2. Execute `CREATE DATABASE` newdb;
3. Reconnect to the newdb;
4. Begin issuing `DDL` statements.

If you're interested in more information, look in to the specifics of how PostgreSQL completes the `CREATE DATABASE` and you'll understand why.

Comment: Sean, I understand postgresql used template1 as the model database, as SQL Server uses the database called model. However, I fail to understand why hibernate cannot be configured to do the same thing if the username and password provided in the config file has the appropiate permissions. I would not do that on a production database for security reasons, but that is a different discussion.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood your question then and I'm not sure. My guess is that because you have to change databases, you need different JDBC connections in order to clear out any potentially cached JDBC information. There isn't anything magical about `template1` so the JDBC driver could very well slurp in potentially stale schema information. Beyond that, I'm going to have to feign ignorance.

Comment: The problem with Hibernate is, that it was developed for server applications, where you expect that a database admin would make his hands dirty by creating a database manually (or by a script). Indeed I use Postgresql in a java desktop application and I encountered the very same problem.